# How to run Ant task from within Gradle Java plugin and a Java task?

Tags: gradle, ant, gradle-plugin, gradle-task

I'm writing a Java Plugin that internally applies a multiple of code-quality/static analysis plugins to add their tasks to the project, so for example I'm adding CheckStyle, PMD, CPD .... etc, now I wanted to add GMetrics which is an Ant task in plain gradle I do it this way:

```
task gmetrics {
    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(name: 'gmetrics', classname: 'org.gmetrics.ant.GMetricsTask', classpath: configurations.gmetrics.asPath)
        //ensure reporting directory created
        ant.gmetrics() {
            report(type: 'org.gmetrics.report.XmlReportWriter') {
                option(name: 'outputFile', value: "${reportsDir}/gmetrics.xml")
            }
            fileset(dir: 'src') {
                include(name: '**/*.java')
                exclude(name: '**/*Config*')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to write this inside a Java Task class, I do the following in my plugin:

```
project.getTasks().create("gmetrics", GmetricsTask.class);
```

Then this GmetricsTask.class look like this:

```
public class GmetricsTask extends BaseTask {

    @TaskAction
    public void gmetrics() throws TaskExecutionException {
        getProject().getAnt(); // <-- can I do anything with this builder OR:
        getProject().ant(new Closure<???>() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // this closure doesn't compile: Cannot resolve Closure
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked at the ant tasks from GMetrics and rewrote a gradle task instead, if anyone's interested I can share it